# How do I immediately select and show the content of a hidden jquery ui tab that is made visible on a button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

On a button click I am making the tab visible but I have to actually then click on the tab to see the content. How can I see the tab content when I make the tab visible?

```
$('#searchPanelSubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#tabs li:eq(2)').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select), in particular the `select` method:

```
$('#searchPanelSubmit').click(function (e) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 2);
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: that worked. I actually tried this first but I had the wrong index. I was using 3 based on starting with 1 than with 0. Thanks